# Password Validation without multiple if-else

Tags: javascript

I have the following code for Password Validation to test different cases and add valid and invalid classes to show the correctness in my HTML file.But I have a lot of if-else blocks to verify all the conditions. I tried implementing with switch statement but not luck. Any leads on how this can be implemented with a lot of if-else conditions. Thanks!

```
var pwdCheck = (str) => {
  var upper = /[A-Z]/g,
    numbers = /[0-9]/g,
    lower = /[a-z]/g;
  if (str.match(upper)) {
    uppercase.classList.remove("invalid");
    uppercase.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    uppercase.classList.remove("valid");
    uppercase.classList.add("invalid");
  }
  // Numbers //
  if (str.match(numbers)) {
    numeric.classList.remove("invalid");
    numeric.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    numeric.classList.remove("valid");
    numeric.classList.add("invalid");
  }
}
```

Comment: Validation block first, store the result in a variable, then a single block that sets classes based on the result of the validation.

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you use [`&&` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) to combine two different conditions to minimize if.. else ladder to single if else

```
var pwdCheck = (str) => {
  var upper = /[A-Z]/g,
    numbers = /[0-9]/g,
    lower = /[a-z]/g;

  //Here you can use multiple conditions to check your password. I used && to combine two conditions
  if (str.match(upper) && str.match(numbers)) {
    uppercase.classList.remove("invalid");
    uppercase.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    uppercase.classList.remove("valid");
    uppercase.classList.add("invalid");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use ternary operator `str.match(upper) ? true : false`, that can reduce your code and improves readability and store `let removeClass = uppercase.classList.remove("invalid");` as local variable